# Or inside condition

Tags: if-statement, go, logical-or

I have this code:

```
if ev, ok := evt.(*ATypeEvent); ok {
   //process ATypeEvent
} else if ev, ok := evt.(*BTypeEvent); ok {
   //process BTypeEvent
} else if ev, ok := evt.(*CTypeEvent); ok {
   //process CTypeEvent
}
```

It so now happens that I have 3 more event types, which all fit into one of the other 3 - I'd think I need a an OR.

But after several tries, I haven't been able to figure how to do it.
This doesn't work:

```
if ev, ok := evt.(*ATypeEvent) || evt.(*XTypeEvent); ok {
   //process ATypeEvent and X
} else if ev, ok := evt.(*BTypeEvent)  || evt.(*YTypeEvent); ok {
   //process BTypeEvent and Y
} else if ev, ok := evt.(*CTypeEvent)  || evt.(*ZTypeEvent); ok {
   //process CTypeEvent and Z
}
```

nor something like

```
if ev, ok := evt.(*ATypeEvent) || ev, ok := evt.(*XTypeEvent); ok {
```

nor

```
if ev, ok := (evt.(*ATypeEvent) || evt.(*XTypeEvent ) ); ok {
```

How can this be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type switch as explained in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch), a highly recommended resource for you to read and understand many things in Go:

```
switch v := ev.(type) {
case *ATypeEvent, *XTypeEvent:
    // process ATypeEvent and X
case *BTypeEvent, *YTypeEvent:
    // process BTypeEvent and Y
case *CTypeEvent, *ZTypeEvent:
    // process CTypeEvent and Z
default:
    // should never happen
    log.Fatalf("error: unexpected type %T", v)
}
```

As for why your approach didn't work, [Go's `||` and `&&` operators require values of type `bool` and result in a single value of type `bool`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators), so assigning to `ev, ok` won't work as you wanted, nor will using a type assertion as a Boolean value. Without a type switch, you're stuck doing something like this:

```
if ev, ok := evt.(*ATypeEvent); ok {
    //process ATypeEvent
} else if ev, ok := evt.(*XTypeEvent); ok {
    //process XTypeEvent
} else if ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define a method on the interface for evt.

```
func (a *ATypeEvent) Process(...) ... {
  //process ATypeEvent
}

func (x *XTypeEvent) Process(...) ... {
  //process XTypeEvent
}

func (b *BTypeEvent) Process(...) ... {
  //process BTypeEvent
}
```

and so on.